# Odoo 10 how to check if Purchase Order "Sent PO by email" action was executed or not

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo 10, is it possible to define a report to list the purchase orders marked as confirmed but not sent by email to supplier?
i.e., how can I detect if in a purchase order the action "sent PO by email" was completed or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using following simple way.

Step 1 : Add one boolean field in **Purchase order model** and update context in following method.

```py
from odoo import fields,models,api

class purchase_order(models.Model):
    _inherit="purchase.order"

    sent_po_via_email=fields.Boolean("Sent PO Via Email",default=False,copy=False)


    @api.multi
    def action_rfq_send(self):
        '''
        This function opens a window to compose an email, with the edi purchase template message loaded by default
        '''
        self.ensure_one()
        ctx = dict(self.env.context or {})
        ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
        try:
            if self.env.context.get('send_rfq', False):
                template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('purchase', 'email_template_edi_purchase')[1]
            else:
                ctx.update({'sent_po_via_email':True})
                template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('purchase', 'email_template_edi_purchase_done')[1]
        except ValueError:
            template_id = False
        try:
            compose_form_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('mail', 'email_compose_message_wizard_form')[1]
        except ValueError:
            compose_form_id = False
        ctx.update({
            'default_model': 'purchase.order',
            'default_res_id': self.ids[0],
            'default_use_template': bool(template_id),
            'default_template_id': template_id,
            'default_composition_mode': 'comment',
        })
        return {
            'name': _('Compose Email'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
            'views': [(compose_form_id, 'form')],
            'view_id': compose_form_id,
            'target': 'new',
            'context': ctx,
        }
```

we have override `action_rfq_send` method & check if user is not sending ref then update context `ctx.update({'sent_po_via_email':True})`.

Step 2: Inherit `send_mail` method of `mail.compose.message`.

```py
class MailComposeMessage(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'mail.compose.message'

    @api.multi
    def send_mail(self, auto_commit=False):
        context = self._context
        if context.get('default_model') == 'purchase.order' and \
                context.get('default_res_id') and context.get('sent_po_via_email'):
            po_order = self.env['purchase.order'].browse(context['default_res_id'])
            po_order.sent_po_via_email = True
        return super(MailComposeMessage, self).send_mail(auto_commit=auto_commit)
```

In above method we have checked if user is sending purchase order via email then set check mark `True`.

We have used simple context to identify process & based on the context, write a value in purchase order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and confirm answer

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Easy and non-intrusive. One question that remains is that I can't find how to translate "Sent PO Via Email" field description. When I run odoo with the --i18n-export the generated .po lacks that msg. Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Inherit `purchase.order' model and add a`Boolean field`.
2. Write `True` to this `Boolean` field in the end of `action_rfq_send'.
3. In `report.py`, select a query to fetch records where `boolean_field =True and state ='purchase'`.

Hope this will help you.